# Is wallet.dat transferable between OS?

Tags: ubuntu, wallet.dat, windows

Am I able to transfer my wallet.dat from Ubuntu QT to Windows QT by backing up the file and pasting in the other operating system?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is nothing OS-specific in `wallet.dat` file.